# Improve "accepted" rates for correctly answered questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I came from StackOverflow, where almost every question properly answered ends up with the best answer "accepted" by the Original Proponent. That's not what happens here.

In one hand, bicycle questions sometimes tend to be subjective, so there's possibly no "right" answer.

In the other hand, StackOverflow reminds users that they should (usually) accept one of the answers as the perceived Best Answer.

Improving the acceptance rates would not only tell other users with the same problem what answer was preferred for the OP, which had the same problem, but also would encourage interested answer-posters to improve their Experience Points (Karma) within the site.

The question is: Should some strategy to improve acceptance-rates be implemented on Bycicles SE, for example, automatic reminders to suggest the OP to accept some answer?

What do you think?

Comment: What is the accept rate for questions on Bicycles? How does it compare with other StackExchange sites?

Answer (score 2):

I din't think this really matters <strike>all that much</strike> as much as voting answers up and down. Accepting an answer is a courtesy, and it's nice to do so. However, in terms of site statistics, what really matters is that a question gets multiple answers and that they get votes. This site does well in that regard.

Are there specific questions you feel should have accepted answers?

Comment: I think there is some value to having the best answer at the top, so that future visitors with the same question find their answer quickly. Upvotes and accepting help make this happen.

Comment: Oh, I'm not saying that the accept checkmark is without value. Just that upvotes and downvotes are worth more. Have clarified the answer.

Comment: But yeah, I'm definitely one of those people who think that people [can be over-concerned with the accept rate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40735/poor-answers-and-accept-rate) a little.

Comment: When skimming the list of older posts knowing it is answered is a data point that may interest some folks.  For others, knowing a question is NOT answered might encourage them to add something to the mix in the hopes of adding value (or just earning points).

Answer (score 1):

There's already a few mechanisms to encourage accepting answers:

1. [Accepting an answer gets the acceptor 2 rep points](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)
2. If you ask enough questions, your accept rate is displayed on questions you ask, such as [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6854/clipless-pedals-that-can-have-toeclips-does-it-exist).
3. There are [reminders to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79780/improve-the-indication-to-askers-that-they-can-accept-answers-to-questions/79793#79793) in various places

Comment: I know about number 3 in SO, but I have never seen it in Bicycles.SE...

Comment: When I posted a question on Stack Overflow someone PM-ed to remind me it was appropriate to mark the question answered (if it was answered).  Is that OK to do here and how do you even do it? I don't see a PM link, but maybe it's a privilege that is earned.

Comment: @Arbalest: There is no PM function available here (or on SO), except for moderators. If somebody comments on your question or answer or does the `@name` thing on a post you've commented on, it shows up in your "inbox". Similar to a PM, but nothing private about it.